# Unhandled Exception as at 0x6ececafa in 0xC0000005 : Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

Getting exception in the following code.

```
HRESULT GetRemovableDrive(
    __out   LPDWORD   lpdwRemovableDriveCount,
    __out   CHAR*     szRemovableDrive )
{
    INT     iDriveCnt                   = 0;
    CHAR   TempDrive[ MAX_PATH ]       = { TEXT('\0') };

hResult = CheckDriveReady( tzDriveName, &bIsDeviceReady );
                    if ( !hResult && TRUE == bIsDeviceReady )
                    {
                        //
                        // Copy drive name
                        //
                        strcpy_s ( TempDrive, tzDriveName );
                        memcpy(szRemovableDrive + iDriveCnt, TempDrive, 1);
                        iDriveCnt++;
                        ( *lpdwRemovableDriveCount )++;
                    } // if
}
```

Getting exception while performing the memcpy as unhandled exception :Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: `szRemovableDrive ` is surely NULL, no other thing can be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is pretty clear. You are writing to address 0 on the call to `memcpy()`. That means that `szRemovableDrive` and `iDriveCnt` are both 0 since that's the write destination address. The caller is likely passing in a NULL pointer to `GetRemoveableDrive()` for that parameter.